# Combining Generated Textures for Displacement Modifier on Plane

Tags: texturing, node-editor, compositing-nodes, displacement

I have a grid that's subdivided into 512x512 quads.  I set up some basic nodes to composite two different (Blender generated) textures.  I wish to take that result and apply it to a 3rd texture slot that the "displace modifier can use to change the plane's geometry.

Basically I'm just trying to use Blender's noise generation to create a heightmap that I can see updating in real time.

[image]

The problem is I can't figure out how to reference the composite of the 2 generated textures.

Is this possible?  I'm obviously pretty newb but any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the "Everything Nodes" development of Blender that should come in 2018 hopefully. They want to do it really really well.

Right now most full time developers are concerned with the new amazing viewport, PBR Realtime, GUI changes for better workflow in production pipeline, rewriting the Dependency Graph (utterly important for Everything Nodes later on btw) and many other goodies coming in 2.8 over the summer/autumn of 2017.

**However, you can bake this! Unfortunately it won't be realtime and you can't animate it. Once you get everything set up it should be pretty fast to update.**

**Plug your noise into Diffuse BSDF, create a non-overlapping UV Map and then bake the Diffuse Color, then save the result and load it as an Image that uses the baked UVs. I won't go into detail on how to bake but all of these steps should take only about a minute once you know what you are doing. No realtime update though.**

How to Bake: https://realfood.tesco.com/baking.html

How to really Bake ^_^: https://www.blender.org/manual/ko/render/cycles/baking.html

Tip: If you are only using a plane and not very complicated geometry, I recommend doing all of this through a camera and not baking it. So you capture the animation from above with Emission Shader set at Strength 1 and then load it up as a Movie (or maybe Image Sequence).

Comment: Lol I clicked on the first link and I was like .. did this guy really just send me a link to a cooking website :)  Thanks for the info very informative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use textures through the compositor or materials for displacement. But, the effect you're trying achieve by just using two displacement modifiers, one for each texture. There are other ways, but they require using the Cycles engine.